# When is potential defined everywhere?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

Let's say we are in the vaccuum. There are two conductors A and B connected by a 10V generator. We can take A to be the potential reference at 0V and B is at 10V.

The conductors are not charged so they don't create potential outside them and they are conductors so their potential is uniform inside.

The potential function V(x) is supposed to be defined at any point of space, so how do you compute the potential in the vaccuum outside the conductors or for example in a third unconnected conductor?

I see no reason to privilege 0V or 10V.

What are some good conditions to make sure V is defined everywhere?

Comment: If you've attached them to a voltage source, why do you think they are not charged?

Comment: Do they have to be charged? sorry I didn't know then. I thought electrons  and protons equilibrate charge.

Comment: So the voltage source forces  more electrons to be on one side?

Comment: The voltage source is a pressure for charges.  When charges are mobile (such as in a conductor), then some will move in response to the pressure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In contrast to you assumption, the conductors are charged, according to their voltage and capacitance, and these charges produce a potential field everywhere outside them in vacuum also influencing other conductors in its reach.